# Desktop on phone

Tags: system-installation, .desktop, smartphone

I have a question about installing desktop system (e.g. Ubuntu) on a smart-phone. I know, there are few topics, but there are emulators etc..

Is it possible to install regular Ubuntu (doesn't matter which GUI) on rooted android phone?

If yes, please tell me how please.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is sadly not how this site works, if you want an discussion you might have a look into [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org). For a question and answer site your question is simply to broad and/or generates only opinion based answers.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the Ubuntu Touch question, and not really off topic, as it's asking a direct question with a direct answer. The answer is basically no.

Comment: @dobey, since you answered 'yes and no' and you're saying it is not to broad for the sites Q&A format care to write a satisfying answer on how he can install Ubuntu on a phone? Within the 30k character limit of an answer. If you do that I'll retract my close as to broad vote.

Comment: There was a thing called "Ubuntu Touch" aka Ubuntu for phones and tablets. But unfortunately the project has been discontinued. Some people have forked it and are maintaining it as an unofficial third party project with a very limited device support. You may visit [their site](https://ubports.com/) for more details.

Comment: @Videonauth The answer is "yes you can install it, but no you can't use everything so easily," hence the "yes and no" start to the answer.

Comment: Related. http://askubuntu.com/q/1332171/124466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes, you can make a chroot with Ubuntu in it, just as you can do with Debian or any other distro. No, you can't run Ubuntu on your phone simply in this way. Some additional software would be needed to hook up the MHL/SlimPort or Miracast display to an xorg (or wayland) display server running in the chroot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explain where's the problem, have a nice day.